# Override ActionMailer from: using gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am trying to override ActionMailer from: attribute in emails. To send mails I have created a sample gmail user account.
My email settings:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => "gmail.com",
:user_name            => "gmail_used_for_tests@gmail.com",
:password             => "password",
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Now, every time I send an email, it's always from gmail_use_for_tests@gmail.com, even if I override from: option.

Is this how it's supposed to work because I dont use any paid service?
I guess that gmail_used_for_testing redirects mails to the requested recipient(:to) and that's why it doesn't override the :from option?